# App Passwords From Outlook.com

Tags: security, outlook

I'm creating an application that uses an email account that I created to send emails. This application is open-source and therefore anyone who looks at the source code will see the username and password and be able to log into my account. I enabled two-factor authentication to circumvent this problem, but I quickly realized that my application would not be able to log into my account.

So, essentially I need to make it so my application can log into my account whilst everyone can see the credentials, but make it so no one else can log in. Does this make sense? If I set up an app password, will that password only work when used with that app or can someone use it on outlook.com for example? Thanks for any help!

Oh, and another option is to make the application closed-source and obfuscate and compress and obfuscate but I've never dealt with securing .NET code so I'm not confident enough in my abilities to make it so users couldn't deobfuscate and reverse the application.

Comment: Why not let people use their own account and make them enter/hardcode the user name and password?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko A few reasons. First, it makes it a lot easier on the user if they only have to enter their email as opposed to their email, password and Smtp server information. Second, some email services deny access to the account when my application tries to sign in via `SmtpClient` unless the user edits their account security options. Third, it would make the user feel better (despite the fact that it's open-source) if they didn't have to submit their password to a program.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want in case of an open source app.